# LPC2148 ISP not working after flashing a hex file

Tags: arm, bootloader, lpc, nxp-microcontroller

I am new to ARM programming and started out with NXP's LPC2148 chip. I am using it's on chip ISP UART bootloader. The loading was working perfectly at 9600 baud with 8 bits and even parity.

Then I flashed a code made by a new project on LPCXpresso through the Flash Magic firmware at 14400 baud. After that the bootloader sequence does not work anymore. I have tried every possible baud rate with odd and even parity but it doesn't work anymore. The common problem saying "Autobaud failed" is coming up and weirdly the chip is warming up a bit when the power is on.

The worst question that is hitting my head is whether I wrecked the ISP bootloader.

PS. I have been using a 16MHz crystal. Although the code that I inserted in it was actually made for a 12MHz crystal with PLL adjusted at 5 multiple (60MHz). But the bootloader initializing sequence should bypass the normal code on chip isn't it?

Please help me

Comment: Did the flashed code include code protection set?

Comment: Well... LPCXpresso free version produces problems with code protection turned on so switched it off... Is that the cause? Now what is the solution? If you want I can give you the code too...

Comment: It should not be the problem if it's off. Setting it on high level can maybe cause problem. For example, in LPC1768 setting code protection to level 3 (highest) disables the ISP port, and chip cannot be reprogrammed anymore.

Comment: How do you put the chip in programming mode? Do you force ISP signal low when doing reset? Have you programmed the chip before; was the chip empty before?

Comment: Code Read Protection was turned off coz it causes problem while building (some memory back counting) ...

Comment: The chip was empty before...

Comment: For ISP I mistakenly pulled it up (3.3V) while pulling reset low... But somehow it booted into ISP mode (maybe coz user code was blank) and then I programmed it... Verified too perfectly... Now autobaud problem persists for every possible combination...

Comment: If it was empty before, chip probably entered ISP mode right after reset. Now that it's programmed, it no longer does that automatically. [Manual](http://www.nxp.com/documents/user_manual/UM10139.pdf) says that ISP should be low on reset, if you want to reprogram.

Comment: Yes I found it out that the datasheet reads ISP should be pulled low thats why I mentioned that I pulled it high mistakenly... Now even after pulling it low while resetting, it doesnt go into ISP mode... And while it is switched on it is warming up a bit... I set the PLL in code to multiple 5 but PLL should not be used in ISP mode isnt it?

Comment: I am not too familiar with LPC2148 , but It seems to me that user code should not run at all when entering ISP mode. So PLL should not matter. I would probably check FlashMagic settings and see that it does not try to control ISP and RST signals, and then do cold reset to ISP mode manually.  I am afraid I cannot think of anything else to help.

Comment: Thanks a lot man... The weirdest part is I spent hours on soldering it and making connections... And if the chip fails... All efforts gone in vain...